# Overwriting class variable and concurrent Flask requests

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm running a python Flask server to perform tricky algorithms, one of which assigns cables to tubes.

```
class Tube:
    max_capacity = 5
    cables: List[str]

    def has_capacity(self):
        return len(self.cables) < self.max_capacity
```

The max capacity was always 5, but now there's a new customer that actually has tubes that can fit 6 cables.
When I receive a request, I now just set `Tube.max_capacity = request.args.get('max_capacity', 5)`. Then each instance of Tube will have the correct setting.

I was wondering if this will keep working if there are multiple requests being handled at the same time?
Are the Flask (I use Gunicorn as WSGI) processes all separate from each other such that this is safe to do?  I don't want to end up with strange bugs because the max capacity changed halfway through a request because another request came in.

EDIT:
I tried this out and it appears to work as intended:

```
@app.route('/concurrency')
def concurrency():
    my_value = randint(0, 100)
    Concurrency.value = my_value
    time.sleep(8)
    return f"My value: {my_value} should be equal to Concurrency.value {Concurrency.value}"


class Concurrency:
    value = 10
```

Still, I want to know more about how multiple Flask/Gunicorn requests work to be certain.

Comment: `class variables` are shared throughout all class instances. You need to define an `instance variable`. This is inside `def __init__(self):`  
Your `max_capacity` variable is currently defined as a class variable.

Comment: During the request I want all instances to use the new class variable. If this were a single process, I know that this behaves as I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSGI applications are typically served using multiple processes - eventually on different servers -, and requests from a same user will be handled by the first available process. IOW: you do **NOT** want to change any module or class level variables on a per-request basis, this is **garanteed* to mess up everything.

It's impossible to tell you exactly how to solve the issue without much more context, but in all cases, you'll have to rethink your design.

**EDIT**:

> how do processes behave? If one of them sets the value, does another process see that value as well?

Of course not - [each process is totally isolated from the others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) - so changing a module-level variable or class attribute will only affect the current process. But since processes are not tied to clients (which process will handle a given request is totally unpredictable), such kind of changes in one process will not necessarily be seen in the next request if it's served by another process. AND:

> Or, is a process re-used, and then still has the value from the previous request?

process are of course reused, but that doesnt mean the same process will be reused for the next request from a same user - and this is the second part of the issue: when serving *another* user, your process will still use the "updated" `max_capacity` value from the previous user.

IOW, what you're doing is *garanteed* to mess up everything for *all* your users. That's why we use external (out of process) means to store and share per-user data between requests - either sessions (for volatile data) or a database (for permanent storage).

Comment: Good to know. It appeared to work so far, but it already didn't feel very safe.
How do processes behave? If one of them sets the value, does another process see that value as well? Or, is a process re-used, and then still has the value from the previous request?